# What is the origin of the phrase "trouble in paradise"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

Does anyone know where the phrase "trouble in paradise" comes from? The earliest usage I can find of the phrase is the title of the 1923 movie *Trouble in Paradise*, based on a Hungarian play called *The Honest Finder*.

Answer (score 2):

[Trouble in paradise](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/trouble_in_paradise): ( from Wiktictionary)

> - (idiomatic) An unexpected problem in a supposedly positive situation, especially in a marital or romantic relationship.

An early instance of this expression can be found in  The   Aberdeen Evening Express ,  Aberdeenshire, Scotland dated Thursday 05 November 1885.

> - “... Job says, understanding is dimmed with words, would permitted to make perpetual **trouble in Paradise**. Kay, he never dared dream thai ... ”

Source: www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

The phrase appears at least as early as 1895 in [*Around the Tea-table*](http://books.google.com/books?id=_ls1AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22trouble%20in%20paradise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9fItVNLFItLCsASJ1oGwDw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAjgK#v=onepage&q=%22trouble%20in%20paradise%22&f=false) by Thomas De Witt Talmag

> He does not like women - thinks they are of no use in the world, save to set the tea a-drawing. Says there was no *trouble in Paradise* till a female came there, and that ever since Adam lost the rib woman has been to man a bad pain in the side.

When it became a set phrase is not clear.